# codename one clickable component

Tags: events, button, containers, codenameone

I want to make a component clickable. I am using this approach : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/hfVoqRwd9lI (create a component with custom style, and set multibutton as lead component into that container).
This is my code :

```
Component[] listingsToAdd = new Component[listings.size()];
                for (int iter = 0; iter < listingsToAdd.length; iter++) {
                    MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();
                    final Map<String, Object> currentListing = listings.get(iter);
                    Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout((BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)));
                    String guid = (String) currentListing.get("seq").toString();
                    Label date = new Label((String) currentListing.get("dt"));
                    Label name = new Label((String) currentListing.get("name"));
                    Label startMt = new Label((String) currentListing.get("start_mt"));
                    Label place = new Label((String) currentListing.get("place"));
                    Label description = new Label((String) currentListing.get("description"));
                    c.add(date).add(name).add(startMt).add(place).add(description);
                    mb.addActionListener(evt
                            -> showScheduleDetails(searchResults, currentListing));
                    c.setLeadComponent(mb);

                    listingsToAdd[iter] = c;

                }
```

But, when I run it, the container still can't be clickable. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiButton` is already a lead component. You should set a regular `Button` or any component that doesn't derive `Container` as your lead.